# How to delete/update by querying on JPA interface?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

The Item table has Many to One relationship with supplier table.

If i delete supplier table row data by Id, its not deleting the row.

The Item table has many rows with same supplier Id. If i delete in supplier table with id, the item table supplier column data /id should be deleted.

Thanks in advance

**Item**

```java
package com.ingroinfo.ubm.entity;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "master_item")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "item_sequence", initialValue = 201, allocationSize = 10000)
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "branch_sequence")
    private Long itemId;

    private String itemName;

    private String itemImage;

    private String itemStatus;

    private String unitOfMeasure;

    private String remarks;
    
    private String units;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id")
    private Supplier supplier;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
    private Brand brand;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
    private BrandPublisher publisher;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "hsn_id")
    private HsnCode hsnCode;

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date lastUpdated;

}
```

**ItemRepository**

```java
package com.ingroinfo.ubm.dao;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.ingroinfo.ubm.entity.Item;


@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {

    Item findByItemId(Long id);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Item i SET i.supplier= :val WHERE i.supplier = :id")
    void deleteSupplierId(@Param("val") String val, @Param("id") Long id);

}
```

**MasterService**

```java
void deleteItemSupplierId(String val, Long id);
```

**MasterServiceImpl**

```java
@Override
    public void deleteItemSupplierId(String val, Long id) {

        itemRepository.deleteSupplierId(val, id);

    }
```

**MasterController**

```java
@GetMapping("/supplier/delete")
    public String deleteSupplier(@RequestParam Long supplierId) {

        masterService.deleteItemSupplierId(null, supplierId);
        
        masterService.deleteBySupplierId(supplierId);   
        return "redirect:/master/supplier/list?supplierDeleted";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using cascade types, for example

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```